Generic type recognized as "any". How can my generic type be improved?
Edit: Solved. Answer edited below
I would like to create a Svelte dropdown  component that accepts multiple kinds of possible items <MySelect options={...}. I've considered several possibilities:

Simplest: Raw string value. The "text" of the dropdown item is the same as the value
options=["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

Customizable text vs label
options=[{text: string, value: anything}, {...}]

Grouped + Simplest. Grouped select
options=[
  { text: "Group 1", options: ["Item 1", "Item 2", ...]
}


Grouped + Customizable
options=[
  { text: "Group 1", options: [{text: string, value: anything}, {...}]
}



I have come up with:
/**
 * Definitions for a single item in the list.
 */
export type SimpleOption = string;
export type LabeledSimpleOption<T> = { text: string; value: T };
export type Option<T> = SimpleOption | LabeledSimpleOption<T>;
export type GroupedOption<T> = { text: string; options: Array<Option<T>> };

/**
 * Definitions for an array of items.
 */
export type SimpleOptions<T> = Array<Option<T>>;
export type GroupedSimpleOptions<T> = Array<GroupedOption<T>>;
export type Options<T> = Option<T> | GroupedOption<T>;

Expectations:

Would be great to not have to specify the type.

Would be great if it could be inferred automatically
let options: Options<string> = [
  {
    text: "Group 1",
    options: [
      { value: "1", text: "One" },  // OK
      { value: "2", fsfsd: "Two" }, // Not OK
      { value: "3", text: 3 },      // Not OK
    ]
  }
];

let options: Options<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2"] // OK
let options: Options<number> = [1, 2] // NOT OK

let options: Options<number> = [
    { value: "1", text: 1 },   // OK
    { value: "2", fsfsd: 2 },  // Not OK
    { value: "3", text: "3" }, // Not OK
]

Currently let options: Options<string> acts as if options had "any" as a type. I can assign anything and it's going to be accepted.

I need to be able to type the value returned as well as a single option itself.
const items = [...]; // Assuming items signature is compatible with Options<T>

<MySelect
  options={items}
  valueAsItem={false} // Meaning item value is Items[i].value
  itemSelect={(selectedItem) => ...} // selectedItem must be of type Items[i].value

<MySelect
  options={items}
  valueAsItem={true} // Meaning item value is the item itself: Items[i]
  itemSelect={(selectedItem) => ...} // selectedItem must be of type Items[i]


Later I would like to be able to dynamically set the label/value attribute name using props. Meaning
let items = [
    { attr: "1", label: 1 },
    ...
]

<MySelect
  options={items}
  valueAsItem={true}
  labelField="label"
  valueField="attr"
  itemSelect={(selectedItem) => ...} // selectedItem would be "1" (type of string)



I'm wondering if it is even possible to achieve everything in TypeScript or if I should rely on any type instead.
Edit 1
Edit: I have been requested to provide "working" demonstration code.
I didn't mean to go so far as to involve Svelte/Components code as
the question is purely a Typescript challenge. 
I've created a Svelte playground for the demonstration.

Type: src/types/MySelect.d.ts
Usage: src/routes/+page.svelte

URL: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/svelte-dropdown-test-mq3tpp


• "Would be great to not have to specify the type" what does this mean exactly? • Very little of your code compiles without error and it doesn't look like you're asking about the errors. Could you [edit] to make sure you've got a [mre] that actually demonstrates what you're asking about? It looks like Options<T> cannot possibly be an array, but all your examples are arrays.  And anything like MySelect should be defined for us. The goal is for us to be able to copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and get to work on it immediately.

I think if you make this change, it'll work mostly like you want. export type Options<T> = Option<T>[] | GroupedOption<T>[];  Options and grouped options should be arrays.

Omg @ScottZ you are 100% right. I believe I just got blind after looking at these types for hours!! It was so simple. Also defaulting T to unknown appears to let me not define the type and let Typescript infers it like I wanted to!

If anyone come up here having the same question, in my case my types were correct except that I mixed up my global type:
export type Options<T> = Option<T> | GroupedOption<T>;

// Should have been

export type Options<T = unknown> = SimpleOptions<T> | GroupedSimpleOptions<T>;

Thanks to @scott-z for pointing this out
